# CSS Layout issue when resizing

Tags: css, wordpress

I have a layout in wordpress, and when i resize the browser all of the content is misplaced.

I have a background image, that is in the body tag,

What would be the best way to fix this?

http://www.arcperformance.com/snackerz/

Comment: Let me guess, you've got a 2k wide monitor?

Comment: I have a wide monitor, yes. But when i just resize FF manually the size becomes misaligned.

Comment: Have you done some `Right-Click, Inspect Element`ing in Chrome or Firebug? You're centering `#top-area` with `margin-left: 430px` and have a static `width: 1045px`. Consider for a moment if that makes sense. At the least, you should have `margin: 0 auto` and apply a `width: 100%` to both `html, body {...}`.

Comment: I fixed the top area. Thanks for noticing that,

Comment: When i re-size the browser all the content moves to the left, but the body background images stays.

Comment: Right. You shouldn't be using an absolute `margin-left: 430px`, because, y'know it'll throw everything off. Also, your `body` `background-image` needs to be centered (using `background-position`).

Answer (score 0):

First thing you do is fix your html errors: [[Invalid] Markup Validation of   arcperformance.com snackerz  - W3C Markup Validator](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A//www.arcperformance.com/snackerz/&doctype=Inline&ss=1&group=0&user-agent=W3C_Validator/1.654). Scroll down in the validation report to see line numbers and source code.

Comment: @kacy: You just broke it further by deleting the doctype; put that back.

Comment: @kacythompson - You shouldn't just delete it; replace it with `<!doctype html>` and replace the `<html xmlns...>` with `<html lang="en-US">` (removing the `xmlns` and `ltr` attributes). That right there nearly cuts your validation errors in half.